# How to perform parallel processes for different groups in a folder?

Tags: bash, unix, parallel-processing

I have a folder containing a lot of images. I have a code which transforms these images into black and white format and then use tesseract to convert them into text files. I have been using the following code to split these files into subgroups:

```
i=0; for f in *; do d+dir_$(printf %03d $((i/(number of files in each folder+1))); mkdir -p $d; mv "$f" $d' let i++; done
```

This command works great to split up the files (puts the grouped files into different folders) but because I am planning on using this procedure for many many files I would like to change this process to be less time consuming (it would take a bit too much time to move the files to a folder). Is there a way I can specify the subgroup of files in order to run a process and use & in order to do multiple instances at once? For example, I would like to run a process for the firt 400 files in a folder and then use " & " in order to run that same process for the files that are in the order of 401-800.

Here is the code that I am using for the conversion:

```
parallel -j 5 convert {} "-resample 200 -colorspace Gray" {.}BW.png ::: *.png ; parallel -j 5 tesseract {} {} -l tla -psm 6 ::: *BW.png ; rm *BW.png
```

By group I simply mean the first 400 files, the second group would be the following 400 files and so on...

Comment: Probably something involving `xargs` and the `-P` (`--max-procs`) option and `-n` (`--max-args`)...

Comment: There is enough space left in this forum to split the above commands into one command per line (and fix the syntax errors while you are at it). :)

Comment: Please explain what the *groups* are. Also show at least a partial hierarchy of your files and directories, how you convert them to black and white, how you invoke `tesseract`, how the results are supposed to look and where they are supposed to be written.

Comment: `d+dir_$(...)` : Syntax error... Technically "command not found", actually, but still...

Comment: @MarkSetchell @lcd047@twalberg thanks for the input. I have updated the question with some more information about my process. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to split them into groups of 400, or even at all? Why not just create and export a function that makes the B&W version, runs tesseract and deletes the B&W version and put the whole lot on to run under `GNU Parallel`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am trying to run 10 precesses with iTerm at the same time. So I want to divide the group of files in groups so I can run parallel tasks and get more images converted in less time. If I just let the parallel code run on the whole folder it will take more time.

Comment: Huh? If you use `parallel -j5` it won't tum away. It will do 5 at a time.

Comment: @MarkSetchell What I am trying to say is that I am using -j (number) in multiple instances. Say I have -j 10 with 10 instances, I would be processing 100 files at a time.
I have been doing some tests and it seems like increrasing number of instances do decrease time but not by a really significant timeframe.

Comment: I must be missing something in your setup. I regularly run image processing on 65,000+ files and I just put the whole lot on with GNU Parallel and it does the lot without needing multiple Terminal windows. Maybe Ole Tange will step in - he is the author of GNU Parallel. Sorry I can't help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my whole ordeal was with trying to use my code on a directory with a lot of files. In order to get rid of the errer stating that there are too many Arguments, I used this code that I gathered from previous Ole Tange posts:

```
ls ./ | grep -v '\BW.png' | parallel -j 60 convert {} "-resample 100 -colorspace Gray" {.}BW.png; ls ./ | grep \BW.png | parallel -j 60 tesseract {} {} -l tla -psm 6; find . -name "*BW.png" -print0 | xargs -0 rm;
```

Thanks to everyone that contributed.

Answer (score 1):

I would let Make to take care of multiprocessing, using a Makefile like this:

**Makefile:**

```
EXT_IN          := .jpg
EXT_OUT         := .txt
FILES_IN        := $(wildcard *$(EXT_IN))
FILES_OUT       := $(addsuffix $(EXT_OUT), $(basename $(FILES_IN)))

.PHONY: all

$(FILES_OUT):
        @echo Generating $@ from $(addsuffix $(EXT_IN), $(basename $@))
        # Do your conversion here!

all: $(FILES_OUT)
        @echo "Processing finished!"
```

**Running:**

```
$ > make all -j 8
Generating file1.txt from file1.jpg
Generating file2.txt from file2.jpg
Generating file3.txt from file3.jpg
Generating file4.txt from file4.jpg
Generating file5.txt from file5.jpg
Generating file6.txt from file6.jpg
Processing finished!
```